# AlarmManager to start multiple IntentServices

Tags: android, alarmmanager, intentservice, commonsware-cwac

Situation: We have more than 5 android applications which are modular (and really limited in terms of functionality) and each has it's own IntentService in which it gets data from internet and stores it locally.

Also one app is core/main app. Now I want, that each app updates its data during the night. I don't want to put code for alarm, receiver and other stuff into every app. I want that core app sets Alarm, and when alarm goes off, then core app calls all IntentServices of every app.

Question: How can I prevent that system goes to sleep during the execution of services?
One solution is that I use @CommonsWare implementation of WakefulServices in every every app instead of IntentService, but I don't really want to change code in all the apps. Is there any elegant way to solve this?

Comment: Switching an `IntentService` to `WakefulIntentService` requires changing three lines of code (import statement, `extends` portion of class declaration, `onHandleIntent()` renamed to `doWakefulWork()`) and adding one JAR. If that is too much work, you have far bigger problems.

Comment: @CommonsWare But what if I create `WakefulIntentService` in my core app, and inside `doWakefulWork()` I call `IntentService` of every app, will this prevent phone going to sleep until every `IntentService` executes?

Comment: The core app would not have a `WakefulIntentService`. According to your question: "then core app calls all IntentServices of every app". *Those* would be converted to `WakefulIntentService`s.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @CommonsWare your thoughts were really helpful.

So to conclude, solution is that every app implements `WakefulIntentServices` and then core app starts `WakefulIntentServices` of all the apps.